# Refreshing a ListView From insider the Adapter without startActivity

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a clickListener inside of the getChildView of an ExpandableListView. When the user clicks on one of the children, that row is removed from the list. I need to refresh the list view to reflect this deletion. Since I am inside of the data adapter, I don't think that I can call notifyDataSetChanged() as I would if I were insider of the Activity where I set the adapter.

I know that I can start a new Activity, but this adds a nearly exact duplicate to the activity stack (and possibly many of them). I'm looking for a way to refresh this list without calling startActivity. If I manually collapse and expand the group, the list refreshes, so i tried to do this programatically, but that's not working either. (note that the group that I am refreshing is always at position 1).

Does anyone know how can I refresh this list view without starting a new activity? Thanks!

```
    public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

       public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> groups, ExpandableListView expandableList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.groups = groups;
            this.expandableList = expandableList;        
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,  View view, final ViewGroup parent) {

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //call method to remove this item from the database
                    //remove item from ArrayList
                    //refresh the view -- this is where I am stuck
                         //tried expandableList.collapseGroup(1); but null pointer resulted
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)

Comment: Apparently I can. Somehow I had convinced myself that this method was only available from the activity where I set the adapter. Thanks!